# error in sonar.java.binaries property for java based project environment setup

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, static-code-analysis

> Error | Java | SonarQube | please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property.

Below is my sonar-project.properties file. I have provided my binaries path. but still, I am getting the error message.

```
sonar.projectKey=Hello
sonar.projectName=JavaPro
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.java.sources=java
sonar.java.binaries=bin/A.jar
sonar.java.file.suffixes=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Is the path valid ? What is the exact output error ? did you provide a path to the compiled classes of your project ?

Comment: @RakeshSinghBalhara `sonar.java.binaries` is looking for the top-level directory containing the _class files_, it won't expand a jar

Comment: @Rakesh please do not edit existing questions if you want to ask a new one

Answer (score 6):

Set your property like this `sonar.java.binaries=bin`, it has to be set to the directory containing the binaries.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me, thank you. ```<sonar.java.binaries>**/*</sonar.java.binaries>``` for maven sonar plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Sonar plugin is unable to find the binaries which means the project is not built first or packaged first
execute

```
mvn clean package sonar:sonar
```

or

```
mvn clean package
mvn sonar:sonar
```